# jQuery - AJAX form validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I am new to jQuery and I try to validate a form. I want to search with ajax and php if title is already in database. The code below wrote by me works and returns 1 if title is already in db and 0 if not. After this I want to add a class to title textfield. At the end I search if title textfield has that class, if true stop the form, else submit.

My script keeps submitting the form even if php returns 1. What have I done wrong?

```
// Process PHP file
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function()
{
    // Show loading
    $('#msg_search_load').removeAttr('style');
},
type: "GET",
url: "ajax_actions.php",
data: "action=search_category_add&title="+$("#category_title").val(),
dataType: "json",
cache: false,

success: function(html)
{
    console.log("Category already exists: "+html.category_found);

    if(html.category_found == 1) 
    {
        $('#msg_search_load').css({ 'display': 'none' });

        $('#msg_search_category').removeAttr('style');

        $("#category_title").addClass("already_exists");
    }
},

complete: function()
{
    // Hide loading
    $('#msg_search_load').css({ 'display': 'none' });
}

});




if($("#category_title").hasClass("already_exists")) { return false; }
```

Here is the HTML form

```
<form name="add_category" id="add_category" action="<?php echo $s_website_url; ?>/category_add.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_category">

<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="120">
<label for="category_title">Category title:</label>
</td>

<td>

<div class="content_msg" style="display: none;" id="msg_search_load"><img src="<?php echo $s_website_url; ?>/images/icons/loading.gif" class="content_msg_icon" alt="Warning"> Searching if category already exists.</div>

<div class="content_msg" style="display: none;" id="msg_search_category"><img src="<?php echo $s_website_url; ?>/images/icons/warning.png" class="content_msg_icon" alt="Warning"> Category already exists.</div>


<input type="text" name="category_title" id="category_title" class="form_textfield">

`<div class="content_count_chars" id="count_category_title"><span class="content_count_chars_green">100</span> characters remaining</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<div align="center">

<!-- Fix Opera input focus bug -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none;" id="WorkaroundForOperaInputFocusBorderBug">
<!-- Fix Opera input focus bug -->


<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form_submit">
</div>


</form>
```

The PHP code used in AJAX:

```
// If category already exists
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'search_category_add')
{   
    $search_category = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `categories` WHERE `title` = '".clear_tags($_GET['title'])."'",$db) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($search_category) != 0)
    {
        echo json_encode(array('category_found' => '1'));
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('category_found' => '0'));
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `console.log(html)` show? have you verified that the server-side script is working properly?

Comment: If you do a `console.log(html.toSource())` inside the `success` function, what do you get?

Comment: @MarcB `console.log(html)` shows me `[object Object]`

The server side script is errorless.

Comment: where are you handling the form submit event

Comment: Chances are you have a submit button in the form without a false return on the submit event, and you've probably attached the click handler to this function. What is this function bound to? A button? Any form event? Post your form code.

Comment: @refactor.me Hello, I posted the form code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to add `async: false` to AJAX settings.

> AJAX is asynchronous, which basically means that it does not block the
>   execution of the script (which is good, as your website does not
>   freeze while things load).

The working code looks like this now:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "ajax_actions.php",
       type: "GET",
       data: { action: "search_category_add", title: $("#category_title").val() },
       dataType: "json",
       async: false,
       success: function(result)
       {
            // console.log("Category already exists: "+result.category_found);

            if(result.category_found == 1) 
            {
                // console.log("Category already exists: Inside if");

                $('#msg_search_category').removeAttr('style');

                validationErrors++;
            }
        }
});





if(validationErrors > 0) { return false; }
```